# Severtimeout during php-request

Tags: javascript, php, json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjl98.png)This is the code that gives me an error.

```
XhrGetJson("fslog.php", function(success, data, time)
       {
           if(success == false)
           {
               alert("Fehler beim Laden der Daten");
           }
           othis.setHistoric(data);

       }, {"action" : "chart", "datefrom" : daterange.from, "dateto" : daterange.to })
   },
```

Problem is server takes over 5 sec. to give response to the Webbrowser.
It's okay that it takes long time, it's a Raspi and data is big and stored on NAS.

So where or how to put a timeout-limit? 20sek would be okay or any other value bigger than 5 sec.

Frank

[BAD request > 5sec.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe2rp.png)
[Request okay < 5sec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjl98.png)

Okay here's te error from the PHP-file:

```
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(http://127.0.0.1:19000): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php on line 269
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught JsonRPC\Exception\ConnectionFailureException: Unable to establish a connection in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php:272
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: Stack trace:
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(193): JsonRPC\HttpClient->execute('{"jsonrpc":"2.0...')
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #1 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(178): JsonRPC\Client->sendPayload('{"jsonrpc":"2.0...')
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #2 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(126): JsonRPC\Client->execute('fslog_read', Array)
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #3 /var/www/html/fslog.php(18): JsonRPC\Client->__call('fslog_read', Array)
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #4 {main}
2022-08-27 18:58:28: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr:   thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php on line 272
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(http://127.0.0.1:19000): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php on line 269
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught JsonRPC\Exception\ConnectionFailureException: Unable to establish a connection in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php:272
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: Stack trace:
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(193): JsonRPC\HttpClient->execute('{"jsonrpc":"2.0...')
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #1 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(178): JsonRPC\Client->sendPayload('{"jsonrpc":"2.0...')
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #2 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(126): JsonRPC\Client->execute('current_logentr...', Array)
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #3 /var/www/html/data_current.php(11): JsonRPC\Client->__call('current_logentr...', Array)
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #4 {main}
2022-08-27 18:58:29: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr:   thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php on line 272
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Warning:  fopen(http://127.0.0.1:19000): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php on line 269
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught JsonRPC\Exception\ConnectionFailureException: Unable to establish a connection in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php:272
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: Stack trace:
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(193): JsonRPC\HttpClient->execute('{"jsonrpc":"2.0...')
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #1 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(178): JsonRPC\Client->sendPayload('{"jsonrpc":"2.0...')
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #2 /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/Client.php(126): JsonRPC\Client->execute('current_logentr...', Array)
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #3 /var/www/html/data_current.php(11): JsonRPC\Client->__call('current_logentr...', Array)
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr: #4 {main}
2022-08-27 18:58:35: (mod_fastcgi.c.421) FastCGI-stderr:   thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/fguillot/json-rpc/src/JsonRPC/HttpClient.php on line 272
```

Comment: The default timeout limit is 30Sec.
to change timeout Please create a info php file and put this into your file "<?php phpinfo();?>"

from here you can locate your php.ini to update limit and can see the current timeout limit as well.

Comment: okay, but that's not the case here it's already 30 sec. If data requested from the server is to big, I can see the python backend is working, working, working but no data is transfered or in my opinion it (what ever) stoppes after 5sec.

Comment: as per the response in given screenshots the response code is 500 which is internal server error. Please check error logs on your server.

it looks like your php file have some error in it. "fslog.php"

if it's timeout issue then it should be 504